# Aviary SDK image editor run error

Tags: android, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I try to implement Aviary SDK in my Android app however everytime i try to run Aviary Intent i get following error:

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
            .setData(imageUri)
            .build();

    startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, 12233);
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx/com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.XXXX cannot be cast to com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.IAviaryClientCredentials
```

I found these article, and i've changed implemented interface but it dont help me.
[enter link description here](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2015/11/avoid-three-common-image-editor-integration-issues/)
How can i fix it?
I follow documentation instruction but without success.
Maybe there is some sample project with SDK and image editor ui?

Comment: I've answered your question below with a link to the repo and possibly relevant files. If that doesn't clear up the issue, please add your gradle code and `Application` subclass to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preliminary answer to your question, there is [a sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui) that you can fork, clone, and run.

Instructions for using it are in the `readme`.

## Points to check

- [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/build.gradle)
- [`app/build.gradle`](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/app/build.gradle)
- [`app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)
- [`app/src/main/java/com/adobe/imageeditorui/MainApplication.java`](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/app/src/main/java/com/adobe/imageeditorui/MainApplication.java)

Comment: Thanks! I found these repo before you posted however these link help me! I think it's very good example :-)

Comment: For the record, what was the cause of the problem?

Comment: Bad declaration Application file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I did not add `android:name=".PACKAGE_NAME.MainApplication"` inside `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` .

`MainApplication.java` contains **Aviary Client Credentials** like below :

- CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_ID
- CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_SECRET
- CREATIVE_SDK_REDIRECT_URI
- CREATIVE_SDK_SCOPES